# How to convert JSON descriptors to cv.Mat format in opencv4nodejs?

Tags: node.js, json, opencv

i'm trying to use data stored in a JSON file inside a match feature function, using opencv4nodejs. The data stored are descriptors from an image previously computed. Everything works fine when the data are computed and then used in code, but not when fetched from the JSON file. 
Data are of type `cv.Mat`, then stored in a JSON file using `fs.writeFileSync()` method. The problem is that the next function using these descriptors expects a variable of type `cv.Mat`, JSON data not being considered as such. How can I use these data stored in the JSON file ?

This process worked flawlessly in c++, using `cv::FileStorage` method. JSON file looks like this :

```
{
    "first": {
        "type_id": "opencv-matrix",
        "rows": 69,
        "cols": 128,
        "dt": "f",
        "data": [ 2.76096805e-04, 7.95492728e-04, 4.21693228e-04, (...)
},
    "second": {
        "type_id": "opencv-matrix",
        "rows": 45,
        "cols": 128,
        "dt": "f",
        "data": [ 3.94702045e-04, 1.63780281e-03, -2.23156996e-03, (...)
    }
}
```

The JSON file shows the data stored, and can be used to store a `cv::Mat` variable with `>>` operator.

I am unable to reproduce this process in node.js, using opencv4nodejs version 5.5.0.
I saved the JSON file using `JSON.stringify()` method on the `cv.Mat` variable, and then `fs.writeFileSync()` method from `fs` package to store descriptors (unfortunately, it seems that there is no equivalent to `cv::FileStorage` in opencv4nodejs). 
First of all, I am unable to see any data inside the JSON file created :

```
{"first":{"step":512,"elemSize":4,"sizes":[69,128],"empty":0,"depth":5,"dims":2,"channels":1,"type":5,"cols":128,"rows":69},
"second":{"step":512,"elemSize":4,"sizes":[45,128],"empty":0,"depth":5,"dims":2,"channels":1,"type":5,"cols":128,"rows":45}}
```

I tried to access `sizes` element through `first.sizes` method, but it only returns the size of the array, not the data inside. I searched, in vain, a way to access invisible data inside a JSON file. Some light on this would be great.
More importantly, I can't use these descriptors in the next function, as it expects a `cv.Mat` type.

```
MSERDetector::MatchKnn - Error: expected argument 0 to be of type Mat
```

I have explored two kind of solutions, with no success so far:

- formatting the JSON file. I tried to create a JSON array, but it has no effect:

```
["first":{"step":512,"elemSize":4,"sizes":[69,128],"empty":0,"depth":5,"dims":2,"channels":1,"type":5,"cols":128,"rows":69},
"second":{"step":512,"elemSize":4,"sizes":[45,128],"empty":0,"depth":5,"dims":2,"channels":1,"type":5,"cols":128,"rows":45}]
```

I also tried to add a key named `mat` (I know it's a dumb one, having no clue of how to format my JSON file, as I can't find any documentation online):

```
{"mat":{"first":{"step":512,"elemSize":4,"sizes":[69,128],"empty":0,"depth":5,"dims":2,"channels":1,"type":5,"cols":128,"rows":69}},
"second":{"step":512,"elemSize":4,"sizes":[45,128],"empty":0,"depth":5,"dims":2,"channels":1,"type":5,"cols":128,"rows":45}}
```

- converting JSON data to `cv.Mat`. I first read the file using `fs.readFileSync()`, then parse the file with `JSON.parse()` method. When trying to convert this variable with `new cv.Mat()`, it returns an empty matrix. I also tried to populate it by hand:

```
const descriptors_first = new cv.Mat(descriptors.first.rows, descriptors.first.cols, descriptors.first.type, descriptors.first.channels, descriptors.first.depth, descriptors.first.dims, descriptors.first.empty, descriptors.first.step, descriptors.first.elemSize, descriptors.first.sizes);
```

This time, it returns a `cv.Mat` variable showing exactly the same {keys:values} as if it were just computed, but giving wrong results. It acts like there is no data at all stored inside.

Maybe my question can then be more precise: is there a way to indicate that a JSON file is of type `cv.Mat`, and if yes, how to do so in opencv4nodejs ? We saw that `cv::FileStorage` specifies a type when creating a file, `"type_id": "opencv-matrix"`. But I couldn't find any documentation or example with opencv4nodejs. And second one, how to convert JSON data into `cv.Mat`, in a way that it actually populates the nearly created variable with the data assumed to be stored in the JSON file ? It can be that the problem is the file containing no data, as I haven't found any possibility to see them. The strange thing, is that I can't even see the data with `console.log()`. On the descriptors `cv.Mat` variable, it shows:

```
Mat {
  step: 512,
  elemSize: 4,
  sizes: [ 69, 128 ],
  empty: 0,
  depth: 5,
  dims: 2,
  channels: 1,
  type: 5,
  cols: 128,
  rows: 69
}
```

And on the parsed JSON file:

```
{
  first: {
    step: 512,
    elemSize: 4,
    sizes: [ 69, 128 ],
    empty: 0,
    depth: 5,
    dims: 2,
    channels: 1,
    type: 5,
    cols: 128,
    rows: 69
  }
}
```

Any help would be welcome, and anyway thanks for reading my question.

Comment: Put your output into a variable and access those as dictionary. 


For example, 

    `output = {"first":{"step":512,"elemSize":4,"sizes":[69,128],"empty":0,"depth":5,"dims":2,"channels":1,"type":5,"cols":128,"rows":69},
"second":{"step":512,"elemSize":4,"sizes":[45,128],"empty":0,"depth":5,"dims":2,"channels":1,"type":5,"cols":128,"rows":45}}` 


You will get something `[69, 128]` for `output["first"]["sizes"]`.

Comment: You can use OpenCV's filesystem to store and retrieve float data from/to an OpenCV float matrix in YAML format natively, completely bypassing the need for an external JSON parser. I'd advise, if possible, to take the former approach, as it is easier and quicker!

Comment: Thank you @testuser. In fact, console.log(output["first"]["sizes"]) returns [69, 128]. But I still can't access any data, nor use this output as it is not recognized as a `cv.Mat` type.

Comment: Thank you @eldesgraciado. I installed `js-yaml` module for node.js. I created the yml file with `yaml.load(fs.writeFileSync("./uploads/descriptors.yml", descriptors_first));`. This time, the file only contains `[object Mat]`, and still can't be used as it is not recognized as a `cv.Mat` type.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I'm writing this as an answer because is way too long for a comment. This is how you open the `YAML` file and store its data in an OpenCV Matrix. The data from the YAML file is stored according to “labels”. We can have multiple labels defining multiple matrices in one file.

So, for example, a file containing your matrix data could look like this:

```
myInputFile.yml:

myMatrix: !!opencv-matrix
   rows: 2
   cols: 2
   dt: f
   data: [ 5.8485,  12.6626,
           6.6515,  11.0982 ]
```

The file defines a 2 x 2 matrix. The data type is defined by the `dt` label, in this case is `f`loat. The way you retrieve this data is by requesting the `myMatrix` label, and using an empty matrix as sink. I do not know the OpenCV java syntax for this; in C++ this is how you do it:

```
//let's read the external YAML file:
std::string fileStoragePath = "myInputFile.yml";

//use OpenCv's file system to open the file:
cv::FileStorage inputFile( fileStoragePath, cv::FileStorage::READ );

//let's check if the file can be actually opened…
if ( !inputFile.isOpened() ){
   std::cout << "Encountered an error while opening the file!" <<std::endl;
}

//parse the data in the input file to a matrix:
cv::Mat dataMatrix;

//Now, give me a label, and I will give you the data of that label:
std::string fieldName = "myMatrix";
inputFile [ fieldName ] >> dataMatrix;
```

Your floating data should be in `dataMatrix` and you can address it normally.

Comment: As I mentioned in my initial question, this works perfectly well with `cv.FileStorage()`. Data appear in the file, and can be easily retrieved. My problem is that it doesn't work in node.js. Data don't appear in the file (there is no "data" key), and can't be used as the file is not recognized as an opencv matrix. There must be a specific way to indicate that a data set is of type `cv.Mat` in opencv4nodejs, but I can't find any documentation on this subject.